# node.js 13 - import is not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js

$ node --version
v13.8.0

Let's create three files:

```
// package.json
{
  "type": "module"
}

// foobar.js 
function foo() { console.log('foo') }
export default {foo}

// index.js 
import Foo from './foobar.js';
Foo.foo();
```

Run index.js

```
$ node index.js
(node:22768) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
foo
```

All working.

And now changing './foobar.js'; to './foobar';

```
// index.js 
import Foo from './foobar';
Foo.foo();
```

And we get an error!

```
(node:22946) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:58
  let url = moduleWrapResolve(specifier, parentURL);
            ^
Error: Cannot find module /foobar imported from /index.js
```

There is no other files in directory.

Why does it happens?
Why import without extension doesn't work?

UPDATE:
https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

> package.json "type" field
>
> Files ending with .js or **lacking any extension** will be loaded as ES  modules when the nearest parent package.json file contains a top-level field "type" with a value of "module".

So './foobar' must work.

UPDATE 2:

> I believe what the documentation call "extensionless files" are literaly files without extensions, not files imported without extensions.
>
> For example, if you import your file with import Foo from './foobar';, and you file is called foobar without the .js extension, it will work fine.

Thanks to @Seblor

Comment: may be when you do it without .js extension it treats it as folder and looks for index.js file by default, so try reading this https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/8427

Comment: look for "Requiring a folder" in following tutorial https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, in the category [`Differences Between ES Modules and CommonJS`](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_differences_between_es_modules_and_commonjs), and more precisely at the "Mandatory file extensions" section, it says that the `.js`  file extension must be present to make the import work :

> A file extension must be provided when using the import keyword. Directory indexes (e.g. './startup/index.js') must also be fully specified.
>
> This behavior matches how import behaves in browser environments, assuming a typically configured server.

I am not sure why your last question is about the import without extention not working *anymore*. I guess you have been working at some point with a transpiler like babel that will resolve the files without the extensions.

Edit :

I believe what the documentation call "extensionless files" are literaly files without extensions, not files imported without extensions.

For example, if you import your file with `import Foo from './foobar';`, and you file is called `foobar` without the `.js` extension, it will work fine.

Comment: @AleksandrKrasikov I think you are misunerstanding what "extensionless files" are.